# Android Studio will not generate a signed aab

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-build, android-app-bundle, android-signing

In Android studio, I selected `build-> Generate Signed Bundle/APK` and successfully created an aab file.  When I tried to upload to play store, it told me my target api version was set to 28 and has to be a minimum of 29.  So I changed it to target 29 in build.gradle by replacing `targetSdkVersion = 28` with `targetSdkVersion = 29`. Then I deleted the generated aab file, jks file, and private_key.pepk files, and I tried running `Generate Signed Bundle/APK`again, except nothing happens. No error message is produced.  I press `finish` and nothing happens.  I've tried changing back the build.gradle settings, but not I am unable to generate signed bundles and APKs.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Went through same problem, just check

1. If using previously created KeyStore and Key:
   Check whether you are entering the correct password for both Keystore and Key that you generated earlier.
2. If the issue still persists, create a new KeyStore and key for the package.
3. If you want to update an existing app on play store and lost your keystore and Key, then no solution is available for this. The update won't be taken and you need to upload it as a new app, entirely separate from your existing app. So, always keep the keystore and key with backups.